# Write to Windows Application Event Log without registering an Event Source Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I need to log my c# application exception into windows event log. As, I have googled and found that the windows service creates the Event Source dynamically for me. Here, I need to know How can I access that Event source specifically to log my data without any admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a(v=vs.110).aspx) is pretty clear that you need to be an admin to create a new EventSource:

> To create an event source in Windows Vista and later or Windows Server
>   2003, you must have administrative privileges. The reason for this
>   requirement is that all event logs, including security, must be
>   searched to determine whether the event source is unique. Starting
>   with Windows Vista, users do not have permission to access the
>   security log; therefore, a SecurityException is thrown.

The recommendation (further down in the same page) is to create the EventSource when you install your application:

> Create the new event source during the installation of your
>   application. This allows time for the operating system to refresh its
>   list of registered event sources and their configuration. If the
>   operating system has not refreshed its list of event sources, and you
>   attempt to write an event with the new source, the write operation
>   will fail. You can configure a new source using an EventLogInstaller,
>   or using the CreateEventSource method. You must have administrative
>   rights on the computer to create a new event source.